# How to SUBSTR a calculated row in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, substring, ibm-midrange

Original Query:

```
SELECT F4105.COUNCS/10000 FROM F4105
```

Output:

```
 Numeric Expression 
  --------------------
  111.1643000000000000 
  111.1633000000000000 
  111.1633000000000000 
  101.7654000000000000 
  101.7654000000000000 
  112.7258000000000000
```

I need to remove at least the last 5 zeroes. I tried to do a substring but it didn't work.

Here is the query(s) i tried:

```
(1) 
   SELECT SUBSTR((F4105.COUNCS/10000 AS 'co'),length((co)-5) FROM F4105  
(2)
   SELECT SUBSTR((F4105.COUNCS/10000),length((F4105.COUNCS/10000)-5)) FROM F4105
```

The 1st query gave me and error:

> Token F4105 was not valid. Valid tokens: (.

The 2nd query worked by wrong output.

```
 SUBSTR     
 00         
 000000     
 000000     
 000000     
 000000     
 000000
```

Comment: Note that this question is for DB2 on IBM i, as indicated by the ibm-midrange tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing the column alias definition in the expression.  So, the correct expression is more like:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(F4105.COUNCS/10000, length(F4105.COUNCS/10000.0) - 5) as coFROM F4105
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this, however.  You have a numeric expression.  Just convert it to a decimal representation that you want, say:

```
SELECT CAST(F4105.COUNCS/10000.0 as DECIMAL(10, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one worked. However the 1st one is outputting only zeros.

Comment: Re "1st one is outputting only zeros": See the _answer_ I just supplied wherein I explain why the 1st of the above, assuming also the `as coFROM` is rewritten `as co FROM`, will approach achieving the desired result, after either replacing the use of SUBSTR with use of LEFT, or inserting a literal `1` as the second argument of the SUBSTR [making the `length(…)` become the third argument].

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for SUBSTR scalar is effectively `SUBSTR(expression, start-pos, for-length)` [IBM i 7.1->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Built-in functions->Scalar functions->SUBSTR](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscasubstr.htm)

The LENGTH() expression shown used in the OP is specified for the second argument; i.e. the start-pos argument.  As a starting position, the result of that `string-length minus five` calculation is conspicuously *incorrect* for obtaining the leftmost data; i.e. the starting-position is five bytes less than the length of the string.  That would locate, of course, some insignificant zeroes five bytes from the end of the string-representation of the decimal-result of the division.

As effective correction therefore, would be either of
 • insert the constant integer value of `1` for the start-pos argument [thus making the LENGTH() expression become the third argument]
 • replace the SUBSTR scalar with the LEFT scalar.
Either of those revisions would achieve something that at least resembles what is alluded as the desired output.  However without either of the DDL and what should be the explicit output being expressed in the OP, the actual effect of those revised expressions could only be guessed.
Anyhow, even with either of those changes, those suggested alternative character-string expressions remain as similarly poor [approaching daft] choice of expressions as the one in the OP, per lack of explicit casting; i.e. the two revised expressions suggested as possibly corrective [yet that remain similarly unlikely to yield desirable results] are:

```
  SUBSTR((F4105.COUNCS/10000), 1,length((F4105.COUNCS/10000)-5))     

  LEFT((F4105.COUNCS/10000),length((F4105.COUNCS/10000)-5))
```

Having established data-type\length attributes using explicit casting [i.e. established even without some actual DDL to do so] in a derived-table expression that generates the input values that would produce the output shown in the OP, from a list of literal numeric values, the character-string expression in the following query ensures that only the eleven digits of decimal-precision to the right of the decimal point [i.e. the *scale*] are maintained; thus visually, the effect is that the trailing five digits are truncated:

```
  with F4105 (COUNCS) as ( values   
     ( dec(  1111643.   , 9, 2 ) )  
    ,( dec(  1111633.   , 9, 2 ) )  
    ,( dec(  1111633.   , 9, 2 ) )  
    ,( dec(  1017654.   , 9, 2 ) )  
    ,( dec(  1017654.   , 9, 2 ) )  
    ,( dec(  1127258.   , 9, 2 ) )  
                         )          
  SELECT cast(  dec( (F4105.COUNCS/10000), 17, 11 ) as varchar(19) )
  FROM F4105
```